# react native debug js remotely white screen on ios

Tags: react-native

Description

i debug on simulator everything is ok,
and run on the ios device is fine,when debug on the device
show the white screen,no error log

Additional Information

React Native version: 0.35.0
Platform: [iOS 10.1]
Operating System: [ MacOS]

Answer (score 8):

This probably means it can't connect to the packager service. Make sure port `8081` is open. If it's still failing, check out `AppDelegate.m` in your ios project. This line is where it gets the js package url:

`jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil];`

You can change it to a custom url like this:

`jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.22:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false"];`