# React Native app stuck on blank white screen with remote debugging using Nuclide

Tags: debugging, react-native, nuclide-editor

##### Steps to Reproduce / Screenshots

Apply all operations from [the instruction](https://nuclide.io/docs/platforms/react-native/):

1. Create a blank React Native project with `$ react-native init [project name].`
2. From the [command Palette](https://nuclide.io/docs/editor/basics/#command-palette) (Cmd-Shift-P), choose "Nuclide React Native: Start Packager" to start the React Native Server.
3. After starting the server, you can prime the React Native Debugger for when the application begins running. From the [command Palette](https://nuclide.io/docs/editor/basics/#command-palette) (Cmd-Shift-P), launch "Nuclide React Native: Start Debugging".
4. Ensure that you are in the root directory of the React Native project, then run the application from the command-line: `$ react-native run-ios` (or choose another existing simulator, for example, `react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone4s"`).

(**Important**: #4 should follow AFTER #3, and chrome debugger should be closed).

5. From the iOS simulator, press `Cmd-D` (`Ctrl-D` on Linux). This will bring up the debug options for your application. For example, select **Debug JS Remotely**.

##### Environment

- Atom version 1.15.0
- Nuclide plugin version 0.214.0
- React Native version: 0.42.3
- Platform(s) (iOS, Android, or both?): iOS
- Device info Simulator/Device? - Simulator iOS 10.2 / iOS 8.1
- OS version? - MacOS 10.12.3
- Debug/Release? - Debug

In [the same doc](https://nuclide.io/docs/platforms/react-native/) said: "...After you enable debugging (#5) from the simulated application, Nuclide will attach to that debugging process automatically since we primed the Debugger above (#3)." So before I clicked **Debug JS Remotely** I saw the working react app as expected:

[image: working react app]

And after I clicked **Debug JS Remotely** I see that the `Nuclide` debugger changed its status from **Starting debugger...** to **The debuggee is currently running.** as expected as well:

[image: The debuggee is currently running]

**BUT** after I click **Debug JS Remotely** I see ***white screen only***

[image: white screen]

And there are no errors. As soon as I turn off remote debugging, everything loads fine again.

This happens with Nuclide debugger only, with chrome debugger, everything works well.

Comment: Although [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40539806/react-native-debug-js-remotely-white-screen-on-ios) described that the problem is only on the real device, not in the simulator and I tried this trick in my case (made changes in "AppDelegate.m") but the issue with white screen still remains.

Comment: Have you tried skipping step 2 so that the it uses the standard react-native packager? (regular packager will be launched in step 4 automatically)

Comment: @ostergaard yes, I see the same white screen with standard react-native packager + Nuclide debugger as well

Comment: Happen to me as well. When I am using Nuclide the debugger can't connect to process. Remote debugging when using Android simulator works fine. Atom: 1.16.0
Xcode: 8.3.1
Android Studio: 2.3
RN: 0.42.0

Comment: Could you please type the same here https://github.com/facebook/nuclide/issues/1080? Thanks.

Comment: same here, any solution?

Comment: @TommasoResti @Stich I was facing a similar issue, the blank white screen, just without Nuclide, and figured it out by running `react-native log-ios` in a separate Terminal tab. For me the problem had to do with the http request to get the js bundle file being prevented: `App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app’s Info.plist file`

Comment: Does your app crash or show errors or warnings without the Debug mode?

Answer (score 1):

check maybe there is no breakage in your code. it sometimes happens when you skip some minor errors.